# CSS animation on hover snaps back to default size after hovering away

Tags: html, css, animation, transition

I have this div where an animation kicks in when you hover it. Unfortunately, when you hover away, the div snaps back to its original size. I would like the div to go back to its original size smoothly. I tried with the transition property, it does not work, and I suspect it would mess up with the animation anyway.

Below is the complete code I used for experimentation (self-sufficient html with embedded css code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Post with edit/delete buttons experiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .post-div {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            border: thin solid lightgrey;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, whitesmoke);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        .post-div .edit-button.animated-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: -25px;
            right: 75px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, #0099ff);
        }

        .post-div .delete-button.animated-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: -25px;
            right: 30px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, #c00000);
        }

        .post-div .animated-button {
            height: 35px;
            width: 35px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            transition: animation 0.1s;
        }

        .post-div .animated-button:hover {
            animation: button-hover 0.5s forwards ease-out;
        }

        .post-div .animated-button {
            color: white;
        }

        .post-div p {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        @keyframes button-hover {
            0% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }

            70% {
                transform: scale(1.4);
            }

            100% {
                transform: scale(1.3);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="post-div">
        <div class="edit-button animated-button "><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>
        <div class="delete-button animated-button"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></div>
        <p>This is a very intesting post</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this much easier:

```
.animated-button {
  transition: transform .5s ease-out;
}

.animated-button:hover { 
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

You will not need to make multiple keyframe animations, css will handle it all for you.

Comment: That it probably what I will end up using.

Answer (score 1):

I added animation button-hoveroff

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Post with edit/delete buttons experiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .post-div {
            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
            border: thin solid lightgrey;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, whitesmoke);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        .post-div .edit-button.animated-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: -25px;
            right: 75px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, #0099ff);
        }

        .post-div .delete-button.animated-button {
            position: absolute;
            top: -25px;
            right: 30px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, white, #c00000);
        }

        .post-div .animated-button {
            height: 35px;
            width: 35px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            transition: animation 1s;
             animation: button-hoveroff 0.5s forwards ease-out;
        }

        .post-div .animated-button:hover {
            animation: button-hover 0.5s forwards ease-out;
        }

        .post-div .animated-button {
            color: white;
        }

        .post-div p {
            font-size: 40px;
        }

        @keyframes button-hover {
            0% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }

            70% {
                transform: scale(1.4);
            }

            100% {
                transform: scale(1.3);
            }
        }

        @keyframes button-hoveroff {
            0% {
                transform: scale(1.3);
            }

            70% {
                transform: scale(1.2);
            }

            100% {
                transform: scale(1);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="post-div">
        <div class="edit-button animated-button "><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>
        <div class="delete-button animated-button"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></div>
        <p>This is a very intesting post</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you it works! There is only one problem, on page load the button-hoveroff kicks in. I should be able to fix it, unless you have a suggestion.